# libswiftDemangle.so on Linux

Tags: swift, compilation, cmake, ninja, demangler

While compiling Swift on Mac machine, there is a dynamic library `libswiftDemangle.dylib` created. I need the dynamic library created on Linux machine as well, however, the dynamic library isn't created after a compilation of a source code.

The file `CMakeLists.txt` at `lib/SwiftDemangle/CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
add_swift_library(swiftDemangle SHARED
  SwiftDemangle.cpp
  MangleHack.cpp
  LINK_LIBRARIES swiftBasic)
```

directive, however the library isn't created.

I use this command `./swift/utils/build-script -R -c --build-subdir build --install-prefix /mnt/servers/swift/install -j4` to build the project, eventually it runs `cmake` and `ninja` to build the project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at definition of `add_swift_library`, maybe it would give you some clues.

Comment: `however the library isn't created.` - What is this mean? Output of build process doesn't show that library is built? Or you just cannot find created `.dylib` file?

Comment: @arrowd good idea, i was lost in the function however - it's huge! `./cmake/modules/AddSwift.cmake`

Comment: @Tsyvarev it isn't created when compiling on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can take a shot at explaining why the library is not getting built on Linux, even if it's late probably.
The main subdirectory containing the library you mention is:

```
https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/lib
```

To build the libs in that directory, which are organized in subdirectories, the following `CMakeLists.txt` is used:

`https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/CMakeLists.txt`.

As can be clearly seen in this file, the library that you mention is only built if the system is OSX/Darwin and not in the Linux case. The relevant code in the aforementioned `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
add_subdirectory(RemoteAST)
add_subdirectory(Sema)
add_subdirectory(Serialization)
if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Darwin")
  add_subdirectory(SwiftDemangle)
endif()
add_subdirectory(SIL)
add_subdirectory(SILGen)
```

As you can see it,

```
if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Darwin")
  add_subdirectory(SwiftDemangle)
endif()
```

prevents `SwiftDemangle` to be built on Linux.
A superficial double check can be to look at:

```
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/SwiftDemangle/CMakeLists.txt
```

which will install or simlynk only `*.dylib` files.
It it worth mentioning that the `swift-demangle` tool (different from what you asked)

```
https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/tools/swift-demangle
```

is built on Linux.